# How to play background sound (music) in GW-Basic

Tags: audio, basic, gw-basic

I am developing a game in GW-Basic.i want to add music to it but the problem is that i am unable to play in the background but when i add sound then first the sound is played then after that game execution is started and vICE vERSA .while i want that both things play at the same time..so any idea how to do it??

Comment: You should look into SoundBlaster programming. IIRC, you could set it up to generate interrupts where you'd fill up a buffer with PCM data, which then is DMA:d to the audio DACs. But I'd really recommend you to _not_ use GW-BASIC. Using something like SDL would be much, much easier (and more portable).

Comment: Maybe you can emulate concurrency :D . Make a fake executor queue. Put  each note just after small packets of work. But That would make it very difficult to create a known soundtrack.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually possible. Use the `PLAY "MB"` statement to enable "music background" mode. In this mode all `PLAY` notes and `SOUND`s are queued and executed in the background while your program is running. You can queue up to 32 notes. Look up `PLAY` in [this manual](http://www.antonis.de/qbebooks/gwbasman/).